# How to define BigUint const in Rust

Tags: rust, biginteger

I'm trying to define arithmetic for a cryptographically large (up to 8000 bits) prime. I'm using `num_bigint::BigUint` for this. How can I define the prime I'm working with as a `pub const`?

I've tried to define the number 2 as a const first

```rust
pub const PRIME: BigUint =  BigUint{ data: [2].to_vec() };
```

but `to_vec` is a non-const fn, and the same holds for any other method I can use to define a BigUint, e.g. `BigUInt::new` so it will give me an error

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `slice::<impl [u64]>::to_vec` in constants
  --> src/main.rs:44:46
   |
44 | pub const PRIME: BigUint =  BigUint{ data: [2].to_vec() };
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. Creating a vector requires a allocation and you can't' do allocations in a `const` context.

However, you chould achieve approximatly what you want using the [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/) crate:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref PRIME:BigUint = BigUint::new(vec![2]);
}
```

This will actually create the data at runtime but it will still behave like a immutable static.

[Example code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6ae02b38659ecc1633426b77464921f0)

Comment: This raises an error for me: ```error: cannot construct `num_bigint::BigInt` with struct literal syntax due to private fields```

Comment: Why do you try to use the struct literal syntax then? This page explains the methods to construct them: https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.2.3/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html You probably want the `from_slice()` method.

Comment: Prefer `once_cell` to `lazy_static`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Why? I've not used `once_cell` before but a quick look through the docs gives me the impression it's a more verbose version of the same thing.

Comment: @mousetail For two reasons: (a) it does not use macros, and (b) its API is going to be part of std.

Comment: Ok, so there is a tradeoff here between "magic" macros that are much shorter, and no magic but more verbose. Overall I'd still prefer `lazy_static` but feel free to add another answer if you prefer another option.